# Traceback with Sockets & Multithreading

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, sockets, networking

I'm creating two simple server-client python scripts that echo commands. That is, the server opens a socket, then client connects, sends a simple message, then the server echoes the message back to the client, which then prints it. I'm trying to make this multi-threaded, and this is where the problem arises.

I'm following [this](https://realpython.com/python-sockets/) *Real Python* tutorial, and was able to successfully run both [echo-client.py](https://github.com/realpython/materials/blob/master/python-sockets-tutorial/echo-client.py) and [echo-server.py](https://github.com/realpython/materials/blob/master/python-sockets-tutorial/echo-server.py). I understand the basic concept and can follow the code just fine. So I added code to to server program make it multi-threaded:

#### server-multithreaded.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import socket
from threading import Thread

HOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 65432
BUFFER_SIZE = 16


def handler(conn, addr):
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        print(f"Server received {len(data)} bytes from {addr[0]}")
        if not data:
            break
        conn.sendall(data)


with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print(f"Connection from {addr[0]}")
        Thread(target=handler, args=(conn, addr)).start()
```

And here's the client program.

#### client.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import socket

HOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 65432
BUFFER_SIZE = 16

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    s.sendall(b"Hello, world!")
    data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)

print(f"Received {data}")
```

When I run the multi-threaded server, I receive the following traceback:

```
Connection from 127.0.0.1
Server received 13 bytes from 127.0.0.1
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "server-multithreaded-new.py", line 17, in handler
    conn.sendall(data)
OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

Furthermore, the client doesn't get the full "Hello, World!" message back (as in the non-multithreaded version). Instead it just gets an empty byte string:

```
Received b''
```

My guess is that somehow the socket seems to be closing while data is still being transferred, but I don't know why. After all, my understanding is that the `with` context manager should handle the closing smartly and automatically.

Does anyone know why this is happening, and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After all, my understanding is that the with context manager should
>   handle the closing smartly and automatically.

Well, yes and no.  The context manager will close the socket *when the execution leaves the scope of the `with` prefix*, which is to say, almost immediately after your thread is launched.  Meanwhile, your thread is still running (in parallel with the main thread), and at some point a few milliseconds after it has started (or possibly even before it has started, depending on how the OS schedules the new thread), it finds that the main thread has closed its socket out from underneath it.

In particular, the context manager in the main thread is not smart enough to realize that you have passed a reference to the socket over to a separate thread that is busy using it; it just always closes the socket when the with-scope is exited, period.

The easy fix for that problem would be to simply make your network-thread responsible for closing the socket rather than the main thread;  for example you could place the context-manager code/with-block inside the network-thread instead of in the main thread, like this:

```
# network I/O thread
def handler(conn, addr):
    with conn:
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
            print(f"Server received {len(data)} bytes from {addr[0]}")
            if not data:
               break
            conn.sendall(data)

# main thread
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print(f"Connection from {addr[0]}")
    Thread(target=handler, args=(conn, addr)).start()
```